# What will be the difference between dielectric inserted quickly and dielectric inserted slowly in an capacitor?

Tags: capacitance, dielectric

CASE 1:
If dielectric is inserted QUICKLY then what difference will we see in the charge , potential, capacitance?

CASE 2:
If dielectric is inserted SLOWLY then what difference will we see in the charge , potential, capacitance?

(Battery is Connected)

Comment: What "quickly" is versus what "slowly" is in the context of a capacitor-battery circuit depends on (1) the speed of insertion, the length of the cables connecting the battery to the, other distributed circuit elements (primarily inductive) , etc., (2) there is also a thermal effect because both the battery and the caps are thermodynamic systems, when the insertion is "quick" there is no time for thermal relaxation with the atmosphere and it is "adiabatic", when it is slow then it can be isothermal, etc. It is complicated.

Answer (score 0):

1. There should be no difference in the potential (voltage) across the plates since, with the battery connected, the potential is theoretically fixed.
2. Unless the dielectric properties of the material are somehow physically affected by the rate of insertion, there should be no difference in the capacitance since it only depends on the final equilibrium state, i.e., the final position of the dielectric between the plates and the dielectric constant of the material.
3. If there is no difference in the potential or capacitance, then there should be no difference in the amount of charge since $Q=CV$.

So what then is the effect of inserting the dielectric, regardless of how it is inserted?

First of all, since the capacitance increases whereas the voltage remains the same there is an increase in the energy stored in the capacitor as a result of the inserted dielectric, given by

$$\Delta E=\frac{(C_{f}-C_{i})}{2}V^2$$

This energy must be furnished by the battery.

When the dielectric is inserted, it is actually pulled into the capacitor by means of positive work done by the electric field of the capacitor. This is energy that leaves the capacitor in the form of work.

Clearly, the work done by the capacitor when the dielectric is inserted will require the battery to do more work in order to increase the energy stored by the capacitor per the above equation. The more work done by the capacitor pulling in the dielectric, the more work that must be done by the battery. So the question boils down to whether the capacitor does more work if the dielectric is inserted quickly or slowly.

At this point we can turn to thermodynamics. In general, more work is done when that work is reversible instead of irreversible. On that basis it would appear that the capacitor would do more work if the dielectric were slowly inserted in the absence of friction (reversible work) than if it were inserted quickly. Which would suggest that the battery will need to do more work if the dielectric were slowly inserted.

Hope this helps.